# google analytics & google tag manager : Where to read the data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I had to integrate the GTM and track few data into a webpage and im facing some comprehsion issues. I dont think it's code wise, but i don't get where i'm supposed to see the data that im tracking.
i've successfully added the GTM code into my application and defined some data to be sent inside the `dataLayer` variable, after that i can go to the GTM admin panel and choose to Preview and Debug, so i can see the data i'm trying to track and everything seems allright. Therefore, i don't know what happens to them next. I don't know where i can see the data that i track, where they are stored. I've linked my GTM account to my GA account so i can see the traffic and other datas, but not the ones i've put inside my `dataLayer` object.

Anyone know what are the next steps ?

Here's some screenshots of my tag 
[image][image]

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Simo Ohava - the GTM "god" - is explaining it quite well:

Datalayer Basics:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/data-layer/

Google Tag Manager & Datalayer:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-data-model/

As far as I understand you, all your questions (including basics and how to access via tag manager - and more) are pretty nice answered/explained there.

Comment: Thanks for those links, sadly it wasn't helpfull. I correctly created my `dataLayer` and filled it with data without problem, but what i'm struggling with is to see those data in Analytics or somewhere else.

Comment: If you learnt how to deal with data-layers and how to access it (use GTM debug mode or Chrome Extension to spot problems), check https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164990?hl=en with detailed explanations how to send data-layer data as custom dimension to Google Analytics. I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding you, but maybe it's also a pure UI problem. Do you know how to display custom-dimensions? I would create a custom-report and play around there. Also inform yourself about custom-dimensions vs. custom-metrics (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

Comment: I also strongly recommend to use Google Analytics Debugger (Chrome Extension): With this nice piece of software you can verify that your data is sent correctly to GA: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

> I've linked my GTM account to my GA account

What do you mean by this? Where did you "link" the data? GTM tracks data via the tags you define to fire for various interactions on the pages, including pageviews, events, and transactions (all known as "hits"). Each tag that fires in GTM has an associated Universal Analytics property ID that comes from your Google Analytics account. You **must** include this ID in all your tags. This is where you tell GTM tags to send your data and this is where in GA you will find the reports on your data.

Simply pushing data to the dataLayer does nothing unless

1. you're also pushing events to it and using those events to trigger tags to fire
2. You've defined GTM variables to grab the data being pushed in
3. Your tags are configure to pull that data into your reports

**EDIT**

To pull data into GTM from the `dataLayer`, you need to do the following:

1. Make sure your data is pushed in the following format:

   ```
   datalayer.push({
      'event': 'your event',
      'page': 'custom/path/path',
      'otherData': 'custom dimension1',
      'otherData2': 'custom metric1'
   })
   ```
2. Create a Data Layer variable, whose name can be anything, and whose value is the name of the dataLayer key.
3. Include the Data Layer variable's name in whatever tag you need the data to apply to. For example, if it's a custom dimension you need to associate to your pageview, then go into the Advanced Configuration of the tag and add the data into the Custom Dimension section (remember to configure your CD in GA, and to include the index). You can be associating any kind of data to the specific tag (eg. page path, page title, page name).
4. Test and then publish your tag!

Comment: Each tag that fires in GTM has an associated Universal Analytics property ID that comes from your Google Analytics account. 

This is how i " linked " the data from GTM to GA, via setting a GA UAID to my GTM tag.

i've attached a screenshot of my tag, i might be missing the 3rd point that would be to configure GA to pull those datas

Comment: OK, what you have in the pageview tag is sufficient. Only if you had other parameters that you wanted to include, eg. different page path, or title, or custom dimensions/metrics, etc., then you would need to grab those from your dataLayer. With the tag the way it is, you should be able to see your visits in the UA-91XXXX reports. You can debug further using Google Tag Assistant, and also make sure you aren't filtering out your visits.

Comment: i think that's the problem im facing, i dont know where to look into GA to see those values ! I'm not familiar with GA and i feel like i'm missing something. The dataLayer is filled with key / values that id like to check in GA, confirming that im correctly tracking those infos :)

I feel like i'm being able to write complex SQL but being unable to consult my db values cause i don't know that  `SELECT *` exists. ( maybe this is a mediocre metaphor, but i'm having issue with how to consult the data that i track )

Comment: Ok that's a wht other set of questions then. You'll need to brush up on GA and how to read the reports. For getting data into GA, you will need to grab data from the dataLayer and pull them into your tags. You'll need to give more information about the dataLayer and also show what you've done already or what attempts you've made.

Comment: i think i'm missing this whole part. According to your SO profile, you seems to be a GA expert, any doc i should read about how to pull data from the dataLayer into GA ?
Right now i only have a `dataLayer` object filled with values.

Comment: i've added a SC of my `dataLayer`

Comment: Your dataLayer isn't in a format that GTM can read. I've included an example snippet above. You can reference these resources: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide, https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/create-a-generic-event-tag/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134997/discussion-between-jorel-amthor-and-nyuen).